# Trying to make a get request using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a get request to my NodeJS server side but it keeps saying CERT_UNTRUSTED. 
The code that I am using on the client side is:

```
function validateUser(){
  var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
  var userPassword = $("#userPassword").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://changelog.twvending.net/ValidateUserByName?userName="+userEmail+"&userPassword="+userPassword,
    success: function(user){
        if (user === "bad user"){
            alert("Your credentials are incorrect, please try again");
        } else {            
            if (user.User.PermissionLevel === 3){
                localStorage.setItem("permission", "hello");
                    $("#newEntry").show();
                    window.location.href = "https://changelog.twvending.net";
            }
            else {
                alert("You do not have permission to make new entries");
                window.location.href = "https://changelog.twvending.net";
            }
        }

    }, 
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
    }
  });
}
```

and on the server side

```
app.get('/ValidateUserByName', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("Origin"));
  var userEmail = req.query.userName;
  var userPassword = req.query.userPassword;
  processInput(userEmail +" logged in");
    var request = require('request');
    request.get('https://32market.com/32marketpcitest/threesquaremarketrest.svc/ValidateUserByEmailULR?email='+userEmail+'&password='+userPassword,
   function (err, resp, body) {
       if (err){
           processInput ( err ) 
           console.log('Error: ' + err);
           return;
       }
       try {
            var user = JSON.parse(body); 
            res.send(user);
        }
        catch(err) {
            processInput('error logging in: invalid user name or password');
            res.send("bad user");
        }  
   });
});
```

My question is what am i missing that the client or sever is not liking. I should also note that this is my first time doing a project like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you don't have the required Or expired ssl certificates to do your request. Probably to `32market.com` does it use an https connection? Is it your own site?

You can try adding

```
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

Before your request

But that isn't exactly secure.

Comment: When I put that in there is says unrecognized left hand syntax.

Comment: I noticed that i put it on the client side and not on the server side. it ended up working when I did it correctly.